# How can I prevent to include same file twice in an included file?

Tags: php, include, require

In a main `index.php` file, `header.php` is included. Both files must insert `session.php,` `database.php` etc. to run. But when header.php is included, there are two same **require/include files**, so there are two same functions, queries. This cause some problems in the file.
What is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Use `include_once` instead of `include`.

> The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that **if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again**. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: That's simply not possible, you must be doing something else wrong. Could you provide us with some code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872629/why-does-session-control-in-an-include-file-not-work

Comment: I can't find any mistakes in your code at first sight; could you give us the exact error (if you don't have one, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top)

Comment: Interesting thing is, there is no error. I addded it both files but browser display nothing

Comment: You shouldn't echo error_reporting(), just add the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. ([6143 is the numeric level](http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.errorrep.php) of E_ALL).

Comment: So, what exactly isn't working?? (because you're not getting any errors)

Comment: That is to say, browser displays nothing when I type mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: Are both files, index.php and header.php, using either include_once or require_once? If so, the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: both of them use require_once. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Why exists there a "include" and not just a "include_once"?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old question but I'm going to answer this, because Search Engines points here if you are seeking for an answer to this question.

You cannot trust users, that they use `include_once` or `require_once` functions to load your script always. To avoid loading same script more than once, you can define specific constant and validate if it is already defined.

File of your script (test.php):

```
<?php
if(defined('MY_UNIQUE_SCRIPT')){
    return true;
}

const MY_UNIQUE_SCRIPT = true;

echo __FILE__.PHP_EOL;
```

If you debug it:

```
<?php
//Lets debug it
include 'test.php';
include 'test.php';
require 'test.php';
require 'test.php';
include 'test.php';
```

Your script is loaded only once and all other include attempts are ignored.

Based on an example one, you can implement similar solution which suits your needs more perfectly.